# Foreach using to draw a html table

Tags: php, html, foreach, html-table

I'm just trying to do a invoice table. I am using "**Fusion Invoice**". So this is the code to take and display items to table.

[image: Lines Of Code PHP]

I want to do a non changing table, that still prints the empty rows.

[image: Invoice Example]

If I have 2 items in my table than add 5 blank lines so in total I will have 7 lines. So if I have 4 items I need only add 2 blank lines to get in total 7. I tried to do with `if` function, but don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably better off with using a `for` loop instead of a `foreach`, Only **if** you always know the maximum number of basket lines, in this case - 7.

Using an [ternary operator](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) to check if there is a basket line that matches lines 1-7, if not - print blank.

```
<?php
    /**
     *  Loop through each $items 
     *  line of the basket as $lines[1] .. $lines[2].. 
    **/
    for ( $x = 0; $x <= 7; $x++ ) { 
        //Does this basket line have an item?
        $hasLine = ( isset( $items[$x] ) ? true : false ); ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo ( $hasLine ? $items[$x]->item_name : '' ); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo ( $hasLine ? $items[$x]->item_description : '' ); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo ( $hasLine ? $items[$x]->item_quantity : '' ); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo ( $hasLine ? $items[$x]->item_subtotal : '' ); ?></td>
       </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Although, you can always substitute the number 7 with a variable that holds the maximum number invoice rows regardless if they're empty or not.

```
$invoiceLines = 7;
for ( $x = 0; $x <= $invoiceLines; $x++ ) {
   //Code.
}
```

Comment: Thank you mate for correcting my question and give me an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you better add some more blank items to $items object.

Comment: I thought about that too, but wanted a proper code which gave me MackieeE.